# System.Runtime.InteropServices error when exporting dataGridView to Excel workbook

Tags: c#, runtime-error, office-interop

I have an application that displays certain database data, and includes a function to save that data to an excel workbook on request using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly. One of my users reports the following error when trying to save to an excel workbook:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8002000B): Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets.get__Default(Object Index)
   at WorkCalendar.Form1.saveBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

We've verified that he does have Excel 2013 installed and all of the necessary assemblies came through ok according to the full exception details, so I hope one of you can shed some light on what's going on here.

Here's the saveBtn_Click event method mentioned in the error above (edited for conciseness)

```
    private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // creating Excel Application
        _Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        _Workbook workbook;
        _Worksheet worksheet;

        string fetchString = fetch.ToString("HH.mm.ss");

        try 
        {
            // Check for existing workbook and add new page
        }
        catch
        {
            // If no workbook found, create a brand new one
            workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            worksheet = null;
            worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
        }

        try
        {
            // do not show the excel sheet being created
            app.Visible = false;

            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
            worksheet.Name = fetchString;

            // Get dataGridView data, insert it into the excel worksheet and format it
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            // save the application

            // Exit from the application
            app.Quit();
        }
    }
```

As I said, the application works fine on my and other computers on which it's been tested. Any ideas?

EDIT: Altered code example slightly to show the method looking for an existing workbook, and creating one if no workbook found.

Comment: Does this bit of code reproduce the error?  Your exception is for a bad index but I do not see any thing other then the Sheets["Sheet1"] that would point to an index error.

Comment: According with @Sorceri th eonly line of your code that can throw that exception is `workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];` Does it exist?

Comment: The first sheet simply isn't called "Sheet1".  It certainly won't be when the user doesn't speak English.  You can index by name or by number, you probably like 1 better.  Assigning *worksheet* again is rather odd.

Comment: Good suggestions, all. Yes, the reference to workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"] does exist, but it only gets called when the method has to create a brand new Excel workbook anyway, in which case the first sheet *would* be called "Sheet1" -- my user does speak English. I can update my post with the full code of my method, but it's much longer than what I'm showing, FYI.

Comment: @bmurrell30 does the code snippet you supplied create the error?

Comment: The other question is; are these 64bit or 32bit machines and which one was it compiled for?

Comment: @Scorceri it was compiled for any CPU, and yes, the snippet does create the error according to the exception details I gave in my post, at least as far as I can tell.